# Conditions on which $Var(X) < Var\left(\frac{X+Y}{2} \right)$

Tags: statistics

This is a problem from the book Theory of Point Estimation:

> Let $X$ and $Y$ have common expectation $\theta$, variances $\sigma^2$ and $\tau^2$, and correlation coefficient $\rho$. Determine the conditions on $\sigma, \tau,$ and $\rho$ under which $Var(X) < Var\left(\frac{X+Y}{2} \right)$.

So what I did was:

$Var(X) < Var\left(\frac{X+Y}{2} \right) = \frac{1}{4}Var(X)+\frac{1}{4}Var(Y)+\frac{1}{2}Cov(X,Y)$

$\sigma^2 < \frac{1}{4}\sigma^2+\frac{1}{4}\tau^2+\frac{1}{2}\sigma\tau\rho$

$3\sigma^2 < \tau^2 + 2\sigma\tau\rho$

I don't see a way to simplify this further. Is that a sufficient condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the quadratic formula or complete the square to solve the corresponding equality:  $$0 = \tau^2 + 2\sigma\tau\rho - 3\sigma^2$$ implies $$0 = (\tau/\sigma)^2 + 2(\tau/\sigma)\rho - 3,$$ thus defining $\kappa = \tau/\sigma$, we have $$\kappa = -\rho + \sqrt{\rho^2 + 3},$$ where the positive root is taken to ensure the ratio is positive.  It follows that the inequality is satisfied whenever the ratio of the variance of $Y$ to the variance of $X$ exceeds $-\rho + \sqrt{\rho^2+3}$.